# Django count on many-to-many

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, null=True, blank=True)

class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=355, blank=True)
```

I want to get a count of how many articles have each keyword. In essence I want to have a list of keywords where I can get each ones count to give it a relative weighting.

I have tried:

```
keyword_list=Article.objects.all().annotate(key_count=Count('keywords__keyword'))
```

but

```
keyword_list[0].key_count
```

just seems to give me the number of *different* keywords each article has? Is it somehow a reverse lookup?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So I got it working:

```
def keyword_list(request):
    MAX_WEIGHT = 5
    keywords = Keyword.objects.order_by('keyword')
    for keyword in keywords:
        keyword.count =  Article.objects.filter(keywords=keyword).count()
    min_count = max_count = keywords[0].count
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.count < min_count:
            min_count = keyword.count
        if max_count > keyword.count:
            max_count = keyword.count 
    range = float(max_count - min_count)
    if range == 0.0:
        range = 1.0 
    for keyword in keywords:
        keyword.weight = (
            MAX_WEIGHT * (keyword.count - min_count) / range
        )
    return { 'keywords': keywords }
```

but the view results in a hideous number of queries. I have tried implementing the suggestions given here (thanks) but this is the only methid which seems to work at the moment. However, I must be doing something wrong as I now have 400+ queries!

**UPDATE**

Wooh! Finally got it working:

```
def keyword_list(request):
    MAX_WEIGHT = 5
    keywords_with_article_counts = Keyword.objects.all().annotate(count=Count('keyword_set'))
    # get keywords and count limit to top 20 by count
    keywords = keywords_with_article_counts.values('keyword', 'count').order_by('-count')[:20]
    min_count = max_count = keywords[0]['count']
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword['count'] < min_count:
            min_count = keyword['count']
        if max_count < keyword['count']:
            max_count = keyword['count']             
    range = float(max_count - min_count)
    if range == 0.0:
        range = 1.0
    for keyword in keywords:
        keyword['weight'] = int(
            MAX_WEIGHT * (keyword['count'] - min_count) / range
        )
    return { 'keywords': keywords}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you want the number of articles that have each keyword, you have to do it the other way:

```
>>> Keyword.objects.all().annotate(article_count=models.Count('article'))[0].article_count
2
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer, but could probably use a little explanation.

Comment: You can simplify it to `Keyword.objects.all().annotate(Count('article'))[0].article__count`

Answer (score 9):

This is the same as the answer from [Vebjorn Ljosa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17498/vebjorn-ljosa), but with a little context, where `article_set` is the `related_name` of the reverse many-to-many relationship object.

```
keywords_with_article_counts = Keyword.objects.all().annotate(article_count=Count('article_set'))
```

To illustrate your results, it would be easier to return the `.values()`:

```
keywords_with_article_counts.values('keyword', 'article_count')
```

Which would return a list of dictionaries that would look something like this:

```
[{'article_count': 36, 'keyword': u'bacon'}, 
 {'article_count': 4, 'keyword': u'unicorns'}, 
 {'article_count': 8, 'keyword': u'python'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes it a little clearer, though I am still having trouble integrating this into my view (see my edited question). If I return a dictionary, then this view will have to be significantly different, no?

Comment: You can return the `keywords_with_article_counts` QuerySet as-is to your view. I was just showing the use of the `.values()` method, which allows you to return a dictionary of desired fields instead of model instances. That was just to illustrate the results of `article_count`, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: I now have a modified version of this working in my shell, but as I am trying to transform the count into a weight and deliver keywords as objects, as per my view above, I am little lost. Any tips on how I integrate this?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how you would do it efficiently but if you need to get it done.

```
keywords = Keyword.objects.all()
for keyword in keywords:
  print 'Total Articles: %d' % (Article.objects.filter(keywords=keyword).count())
```